# Conditional logic for submit button in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way to make the form un-submittable until certain requirements have met? More specifically a minimum price value.

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Currently Range Validation (ie min and/or max values) is supported on Number, Date, and Currency fields.  We have recently added support to support this same Range Validation on Price and Calculation fields.  That feature will be released early next week.

To enable this Range Validation add the appropriate field to the builder. At the bottom of the Field Settings there is a Range option that supports both Minimum and Maximum Values. This can be used to require that the input of the field is between the specified Minimum and Maximum values.  You do not have to enter both a Min and a Max, you can specify one, the other, both, or neither. The Min/Max values can specify either a static value or calculation.

[image: Field Settings]